# Xcode display build output in console

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

So maybe this is a dumb question, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the play-by-play build output for an iPhone app to appear in some kind of console.

I need to verify whether a certain build step is occurring or not, so I need to get the line-by-line output from the build. In Android, this is a trivial task, but it seems not so easy in Xcode.

By that I mean I want an output that looks roughly like this, without having to watch the tiny little box in the top center of the screen:

```
Starting build...
Fooing bar...
Reticulating splines...
Compiling source code...
Linking...
Uploading debug symbols...
Transferring $50k to bank account...
Build SUCCESS after 2m 30s
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build output is available in the *Report Navigator*

[image]

Comment: I would have never found that in a million years - classic Apple UI.